# Elm.js "lift" and Bacon.map: Are they functionally the same?

Tags: frp, elm, bacon.js

I'm trying to understand Elm.  I have a bit of experience with Bacon.js, and it seems to me that lift is, basically, Bacon.js's internal map() function renamed.

Is there more to it than that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, that's the same thing. With the `lift2..8` functions you can do the same thing that you'd do with `Bacon.combineWith`.

Signals in Elm (just like Properties in Bacon) are Functors and Applicative Functors, where the former allows you to lift an unary function to the realm of Signals (Elm: `lift`, Bacon: `map`, Rx: `select`), while the latter allows you to lift `n-ary` functions (Elm: `lift2..8`, Bacon: `combineWith`, Rx: `combineLatest`).

Comment: Can you give some background of the "lift" term?

Comment: "Lifting is a concept which allows you to transform a function into a corresponding function within another (usually more general) setting." http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lifting